# Ubuntu 20.04 blinking screen

Tags: drivers, graphics, hp, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

It all started today afternoon as I removed power cable from laptop when its 90%+ charged.

It gave a full horizontal line top of the desktop. Then I got constant such blinks on my screen, not a big annoying, but it keep happening.

I have tried updating bios, and also Try ubuntu without installing, but it kept getting.

All I need to know is

1. What would be the issue? physically damaged motherboard?
2. Can I get normal working with Graphic driver installation?
3. Should I keep using this laptop with this error or stop using till proper checkup? (by a professional)

HP Probook G6 455, AMD Ryzen r7 2900 with inbuild graphics.
Kernel : 5.8.55

This is what I captured during bios update. https://youtu.be/a5xphdsjJOQ

Comment: Try this. Shutdown the laptop. Hold down the power button for ~30 seconds. This will reset the Power Manager. Reboot and retest. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema just did and still the same.

Comment: Log into a different user account (create one if you need to) and see if the same problem occurs. Show me a screenshot.

Comment: Open your Displays settings panel, and tell me what the **Resolution** and **Refresh Rate** are set to.

Comment: Resolution : 1366*768, Refresh rate : 60.06Hz

Comment: @heynnema Yes, other user also have the same. I got a video, should I upload??

Comment: Yes, screenshot or video. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126186/discussion-between-sachith-muhandiram-and-heynnema).

Comment: @heynnema All mem test ran and it was success. No errors.

Comment: You may have a hardware problem. Is the computer still under warranty? Take it to a repair depot. You already updated the BIOS, yes?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I updated BIOS, now its of warranty period.should I stop using it at any cost?

Comment: I assume that you mean "out of warranty"? I believe your video card may be bad. Use the computer if you can, but I'd still take it to a (factory authorized) repair depot. Do you have Windows on this computer? If so, does the problem also show up there?

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the all the support given. Only issue right now is extended lockdown.

Comment: Does Windows show a similar problem?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, windows also have, but it doesnt get that horizontal line at the top, just screen